# Could there be a hybrid particle made of one quark and one or several gluons?

Tags: quantum-chromodynamics, quarks, quark-gluon-plasma

The question's background is that such a quark-gluon bound state
might be colour-less.

But it seems that no such particle is ever mentioned.
Is there a reason speaking against its existence?

ADDED:

Cosmas Zachos explained below that one quark and one gluon cannot do the trick.

Could one quark and several gluons form a bound state? It seems that this should also impossible.

Comment: You are definitely in error here: it is impossible to make a color singlet by composing a color octet with a color triplet.

Comment: Cann you explain in more detail? I (mistakenly) thought that a red quark and a blue-green gluon could do the trick. How can I make this more clear in my head?

Comment: I suppose that this is because there is no blue-green gluon, only a blue-antigreen one. Is that the way to put it for simple people like me?

Comment: Making a fool of myself again: is an electron-gluon composite possible? Maybe with two gluons?

Comment: A two gluon color singlet is possible (glueball), but there would be nothing to bind the electron to it, since the electron is not colored (singlet).

Answer (score 2):

If you want, here are  the  technicalities to @Cosmos Zachos comment: The quark are in the 3 representation of ${\rm SU}(3)$ colour and the Gluons are in the 8 adjoint representation. The tensor product
$$
3\otimes 8 =15\oplus 6\oplus 3
$$
does not contain a 1, so no singlet can be made. There is some good discussion in the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clebsch%E2%80%93Gordan_coefficients_for_SU(3))